# Access a specific array item in handlebars inside a IF condition

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I am working with handlebars for the first few times and I couldnt find any answer for this.

I have an handlebars object: `{{product.options}}`, which outputs the number of swatches which are active for a particular product.

So if I will have 3 color swatches, the output for `{{product.options}}` would be [object Object],[object Object],[object Object].

What I am trying to achieve, is to target every color swatch output and assign a unique source media element to it.So after the user clicks on a specific swatch a representative thumbnail image to that swatch will load.

Now this is done by default in the panel for the product for each individual SKU, but you can upload just one image. I need to do this because I want to have different image for mobile and for desktop for all the swatches.

So far, I got this code

```
 {{#if product.options}}
    <source media="(min-width: 768px)"
        srcset="{{getImage ../product.images.[6] (cdn theme_settings.default_image_product)}}">
    <source media="(min-width: 768px)"
        srcset="{{getImage ../product.images.[7] (cdn theme_settings.default_image_product)}}">
 {{/if}}
```

It loads the alternative images for desktop, but I have no idea how to specifically assign them to a specific color swatch. I was trying it with `{{#if @index '===' 0`}} and so on, for specifying the different scenarios but nothing worked.

And here is the whole picture class

```
<picture class="productLayout-one-picture fullwidth-image-container productView-image is-ready" data-image-gallery-main>
{{#if product.options}}
    <source media="(min-width: 768px)"
            srcset="{{getImage ../product.images.[6] (cdn theme_settings.default_image_product)}}">
    <source media="(min-width: 768px)"
        srcset="{{getImage ../product.images.[7] (cdn theme_settings.default_image_product)}}">
{{/if}}

    <img class="productView-image--default fullwidth-image"
         data-sizes="auto"
         src="{{getImage product.main_image (cdn theme_settings.default_image_product)}}"
         alt="{{product.main_image.alt}}" title="{{product.main_image.alt}}" data-main-image >
</picture>
```

The 'default' thumbnail images are switching correctly when clicked on a different swatch, that is the basic functionality of bigcommerce cornerstone theme, but I do not know how to replicate these conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of `#each` and `#if_eq` helpers for that comparison.

```
{{#if product.options}}
    {{#each product.options}}
       {{#if_else index compare=0 }}
           // .. do something specific
       {{/if_else}}
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

**if_eq.js**

```
export default function(context, options) {
    var compare = options.hash.compare;

    if(compare && context) {
        compare = compare.toString();
        context = context.toString()
    }

    if (context === compare) {
        return options.fn(this);
    }

    return options.inverse(this);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it didnt really went through :(

Comment: Its been a while I have used handlebars, my bad, looks like `if_eq` is a custom handlebar template that needs to be added ( need to configure handlebars for that )